# "Error: Undefined class constant 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::SCOPE_CONTAINER'"

Tags: 8, drush

I am using drush 8.1.2 and drupal 8.1.

I ran `composer update` in /core as well as in the project root.  From what I can see it updates /core/vendor as well as /vendor (in project root).

Obviously this means that many of the libraries are duplicated; I am not sure if this is the idea.

Anyhow, when execute any drush command from /sites/default I get the following error:

> Error: Undefined class constant 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::SCOPE_CONTAINER' in
>   /myproject/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Container.php, line 16

If I open core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Container.php in my IDE (PHPStorm), the IDE tells me there are multiple definitions for `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface`, which is fair enough because there is one in core/vendor as well as vendor (in the project root).

Either way, the versions of `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface` is exactly the same (version 2.8.6)

According to [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2704943), it is important that they are the same, which they are, and the class constant is defined in both files.

I get the impression, the file is not being 'auto-loaded', but I do not know enough about Drupal 8 to figure out if it is or not.

For the record, when I open the project in my browser (hit the web site), it is working fine.

So the drush / drupal boot-strap process is not working.

Any ideas where to start looking please.

Comment: Just a side note - I installed a clean D8.1 site, and when I execute drush pm-list I get the same error; so the problem is not the fact that I ran composer update on my project.  The problem is either in core or drush (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly that you executed `composer update` twice, in two different directories. You don't execute it from the core directory, but only from the directory containing the core directory. In fact, the composer.json file you find in the directory where you decompressed the Drupal archive contains the following lines.

```
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json",
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    }
```

The `include` part is telling to Composer to include the core/composer.json file too when updating. Supposing that mysite is the directory containing the core directory and the other Drupal files, it is enough you execute the following commands to get in mysite/vendor all the dependencies necessary.

```
cd mysite
composer update
```

In my case, I get the following output. (It may change, basing on how often you execute those commands.)

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>      Removing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.1.1)
>      Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.2.0)
>        Downloading: 100%
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>     Removing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.1.1)
>     Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.2.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>     Removing symfony/polyfill-php54 (v1.1.1)
>     Installing symfony/polyfill-php54 (v1.2.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>     Removing symfony/polyfill-php55 (v1.1.1)
>     Installing symfony/polyfill-php55 (v1.2.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>     Removing guzzlehttp/promises (1.1.0)
>     Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.2.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>     Removing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.1.1)
>     Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.2.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>   Writing lock file
>   Generating autoload files
>    Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
>    Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess

Both Drupal 8 and Drush work for me.

```
drush status
```

> Drupal version                  :  8.1.1
>   Site URI                        :  http://default
>   Database driver                 :  mysql
>   Database hostname               :  localhost
>   Database port                   :
>   Database username               :  database_username
>   Database name                   :  database_name
>   Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
>   Drupal user                     :
>   Default theme                   :  bartik
>   Administration theme            :  seven
>   PHP configuration               :  /etc/php.ini
>   PHP OS                          :  Darwin
>   Drush script                    :  /usr/local/bin/drush
>   Drush version                   :  8.0.5
>   Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
>   Drush configuration             :
>   Drush alias files               :
>   Install profile                 :  standard
>   Drupal root                     :  /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/mysite
>   Drupal Settings File            :  sites/default/settings.php
>   Site path                       :  sites/default
>   File directory path             :  sites/default/files
>   Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
>   Sync config path                : sites/default/files/config_WZrobbGFfHIWBRmKDknFVfKgdyG1gKNFLBYcpBlbTZtEarG_rPEixLJFW6faE9yNFTjdkieQbA/sync

As side note, if you need to include the composer.json files modules could have, you can edit the mysite/composer.json file to contain the following lines.

```
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json",
            "modules/*/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) module. I would suggest installing it, if you need to include any dependecy modules could have.

Comment: thanks @kiamlaluno.  I will remember the composer update advice.  In my case the problem was drush was installed globally (also via composer) and in my .composer/vendor I had version 3.x of the dependancy-injection library; When I forced that library to ~2, drush started working just fine.